# crypto-js throws compile error in Unity

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unityscript, cryptojs

I am working on an app that currently stores user passwords in plain-text.  After a bit of research, I decided to opt for SHA3 from the crypto-js library to accomplish this task.  I downloaded the SHA3 rollup and placed it (unmodified) in the same folder as the scripts I intended to use it in.  Unity, however, immediately throws a compile error:

```
Assets/Scripts/StartMenu/sha3.js(7,46): BCE0043: Unexpected token: ,.
```

Googling the error yields various issues with syntacticly incorrect code.  My research led me to believe that crypto-js was the go-to implementation for js, so I doubt there's an issue with the library.  Does Unity differ greater in it's JS implementation?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Unity is not really using JavaScript, but UnityScript. Unityscript and Javascript are essentially different languages; it's mostly a marketing move to call it "Javascript" in Unity. Some of the differences can be found [here](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Head_First_into_Unity_with_UnityScript) and [here](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=UnityScript_versus_JavaScript). If anything I would advice you to switch over to C#.

Comment: Thanks, I'll start checking these out.